# How do I launch xbuild (mono) with .NET Framework 4.5 using Albacore 2?

Tags: c#, mono, albacore

How can I configure the build task to launch mono under the .net 4.5 runtime? Preferably based on settings in my solution file rather than passing a setting directly. With the current configuration xbuild is launched using the .net 4.0 runtime.

```
task :build => [:compile_this]

build :compile_this do |b|
  b.file = 'MyProj.sln'
  b.target = ['Clean','Rebuild']
  b.prop  :configuration ,'Debug'
end

test_runner :test => [:build] do |cmd|
  cmd.command = '~/bin/xunit/xunit.console.exe'
  cmd.files = ['Tests/bin/Tests.dll']
  cmd.add_parameter = '/html results.html'
end
```

I am running mono 3.2.7 64bit under Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to sit down and figure this all out.

Upgrading mono to 3.8 and removing the target and prop elements and adding in `tools_version= '12.0'` got things working correctly. (Note that I am not certain that using 3.8 was necessary to get this to work.

My build task looks like this

```
build :compile_this do |b|
  b.sln = 'MyProj.sln' 
  b.tools_version = '12.0'
end
```